# MySQL: See if a value exists in the first 1000

Tags: mysql

How to check if a value exists in the first 1000 rows, and if it does return information.

Something like

```
select cme_fbid 
from table1 if exists(select cme_fbid from table1 limit 1000)
```

Comment: select cme_fbid from table1 where cme_fbid!='' limit 1000 ? =)

Comment: And it is nice when somebody ask about sql query to show table structure so that we can help you with real example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the subquery to limit the data that you look at:

```
select cme_fbid 
from (select * from table1 order by someThing limit 1000) x
where someField = someValue
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT cme_fbid FROM table1 LIMIT 1000) THEN t.cme_fbid
        ELSE NULL
    END
    FROM table1 t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select cme_fbid 
from table1
where cme_fbid in (
    select cme_fbid
    from table1
    limit 1000)
```

You probably want to add an `order by` to the inner query to get consistent/meaningful results.

Answer (score 0):

`select count(*) as cnt from table1 where cme_fbid is not null and cme_fbid <> 0 limit 1000 order by id`

or using `mysql_row_count` on

`select cme_fbid from table1 where cme_fbid is not null and cme_fbid <> 0 limit 1000 order by id`